# Typescript: Why doesn't my code compile if a property value comes from a nested object?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I apologize for the poor title, but I don't have the vocabulary to word it better. Let me show you my code:

```
type Foo = "bar" | "baz";

type Consistency  = {
    [K in Foo]: {
        foo: K;
        fooTemplate: `${K} in a template`;
    }
}[Foo]

// I want this to compile (and it does)
const valid1: Consistency = {
    foo: "bar",
    fooTemplate: "bar in a template",
}

const valid2: Consistency = {
    foo: "baz",
    fooTemplate: "baz in a template",
}

export const anFoo: Foo = "bar"

const valid3: Consistency = {
    foo: anFoo,
    fooTemplate: `${anFoo} in a template` as const
}

export interface MyObj {
  temporary: {    
    myProperty: Foo;    
  };
}
const state: MyObj = {
    temporary: {
        myProperty: "bar" 
    }
}
const i: Foo = state.temporary.myProperty;
const valid4: Consistency = { // Why doesn't this one compile????
    foo: i,
    fooTemplate: `${i} in a template` as const
}

// I don't want this to compile (and it doesn't)
const invalid1: Consistency = {
    foo: "bar",
    fooTemplate: "baz in a template",
}

const invalid2: Consistency = {
    foo: "baz",
    fooTemplate: "bar in a template",
}
```

[You can play with this here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAiARgQwE6qgHzSwC9UBuAKAtEigGE4A7AZwEtngJGBjEKZKAG8K-fgG0A0lFaNYCALoAuISNFqAZgmUTKajQgAqEALZgANpk7KABgBJBEgL7TZmKJ1MXO13aMcVHMXg4eSoAejCoAEkoAHdMRmB3AAt2d0RuOFNWM2gACgSAE2kkwrgIZgBKCkyWJIA3TDNWQoBGZQYWdk4ePhRhfThlDBxUABpVfk04I09LCGGsbBcoNw9zefGAqlqOKEbmwoAmDqY2Di5eAQHRacXMUgnB2Y2rIgeVtZNXiC3-CggAA8wHBsEldkkEsFlMEBCNcDszg0mi0AMynLoXXrXSZQO6rRjBJ63QzfLwLKB2QRQhDOGSrdxk+bWVbMKAQ7YA4GgpIyTjYdSYbjQACyIAA8ugAFYqfjrUE4EDKQRqXHGEAABWwcEgYKVcjgZFV-EclH8EKgHHmyjFkpl-Vx8uwiuVuLU6q1OogevuuCguP85qR0hhCAEVs4ADonYrIx7tbrQJQLQcWgAWDHnHpXfpQCJQADqyT4ZQqjAA5ElgKk2UxoJlsrkAPwtpu4-GsYlTUlzN5U1h01yM3sQFmYNkc-75mJlCtJeKJFJpYAZLJgHL5IolKCl5hz6oWmSptqZ7qXPqyklDd64Lt4ns-e7ET7Dn5-RF1FzHk70M5n7EOoMT5bM8TJvPCL7rOSfxAA) This all works the way I expect accept for `valid4`. For some reason, `valid4` doesn't compile, and I want it to.  Why isn't it compiling and how do I make it compile?

---

The answer doesn't explicitly say this so I will: There's no solution to this problem.

Comment: I've seen this error before where a union is not assignable to itself because the union is not assignable to either individual member.  I bet @jcalz can come along and explain it better than I can.  You have `i` and you as the author know that it's the same `i` in both places, but TS is just looking at `i` as type `Foo`.  It is possible to have a type `Foo` in both places and not be assignable to `Consistency` if one `Foo` is `"bar"` and the other `Foo` is `"baz"`.  so the type `Foo` cannot guarantee assignability.

Comment: It's not about nested objects, it's just that `anFoo` is typed as `"bar"` and not as `Foo`. `declare const anFoo: Foo` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is this, but maybe Jcalz can correct me.

Unions of "A" | "B" actually have 3 assignability's.

"A" is assignable.
"B" is assignable.
And "A" | "B" is assignable

Its this third case that breaks valid4.
At a value level this is impossible, but at a type level its possible that its both "bar" | "baz" and therefore it thinks...

```
{foo: "baz", fooTemplate: "bar as template"}
```

is possible.

As for valid3, this is because Typescript compiler can detect you've hardcoded the value there and therefore even though you're asserting "Foo" the actual type it considers that is "bar"

Comment: This looks right to me... the compiler mostly doesn't care about *variables* per se, but about the *types* of the variables.  There's no great way to have the compiler follow correlations between two union-typed values automatically; you have to drag the compiler through the separate cases like ```i === "bar" ? { foo: i, fooTemplate: `${i} in a template` as const } : { foo: i, fooTemplate: `${i} in a template` as const }```, which looks like another instance of [this problem](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Comment: @jcalz since that links to an open issue, does that mean there's no solution?

Comment: There's no perfect solution, no.  There are workarounds, of course: either use redundant code like the above ternary and get type safety, or use a type assertion like ```{ foo: i, fooTemplate: `${i} in a template` as const } as Consistency;``` and get convenience.  You can't have both, as far as I know.